# Google Play Game Services & Custom Server Logic Using Node.JS and Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, socket.io, server, google-play-services

Like the Title explains all...
is it possible to integrate GPGS and Node.Js for making a multiplayer game?
Instead of using REST API's...

Thank you